# php filter empty array

Tags: php, array-filter

How to remove empty data from an array?

```
var_dump($array);

array(1)  
  {    [0]=>     
    array(4) 
    { 
     [0]=> string(0) "" 
     [1]=> string(3) "car" 
     [2]=> string(4) "bike"
     [3]=> string(1) " " 
    }   
  }
```

I add `array_filter($array);` nothing removed. so how to remove `""` and `" "` or if have more empty `space` in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're trying to achieve this behavior:

```
<?php
$foo = array(
    array(
        'foo',
        ' ',
        'bar',
        0,
        false,
    ),
);

function array_clean(array $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $haystack[$key] = array_clean($value);
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            $value = trim($value);
        }

        if (!$value) {
            unset($haystack[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $haystack;
}

print_r(array_clean($foo));
```

The script will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [2] => bar
        )

)
```

Right?

Comment: That's quite elaborate. Generic enough to allow nested arrays, but it will still leave the number 1, while removing string '0'.

Answer (score 12):

```
$array = array_filter($array, 'trim');
```

[edit]

This will indeed fail on some values like `'0'`, and non-string values.

A more thorough function is:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($a){
    return is_string($a) && trim($a) !== "";
});
```

This will only return strings that fit your request.

Comment: What do you mean? Yes it does.

Comment: @codaddict Yes, you're right, although you should always consider what your input will be and how far you want to go. Anyway, I posted an alternative that is just a little more code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a callback function which trims whitespace from the input element and return `TRUE` if the trimmed element isn't empty:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($x) { 
  $x = trim($x);
  return !empty($x);
});

// Example:
$array = array(1,2,"",3," ",5);

print_r($array);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [5] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc of [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) :

```
$entry = array(
             0 => 'foo',
             1 => false,
             2 => -1,
             3 => null,
             4 => ''
          );

print_r( array_filter( $entry ) ); //Array ( [0] => foo [2] => -1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// removes all NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings but leaves 0 (zero) values
$result = array_filter( $array, 'strlen' );
```